# Converting Point to Button

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, point

Is it possible to convert from point to JButton in java, just as you convert from `int` to `string` .. Any help is acceptable, please I need help on it. Thanks!

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;

    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.*;


    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Beginner extends JPanel {

        static JButton quest;
        Random rand = new Random();

        int n = 10;

        static List <Point> points = new ArrayList<Point> ();


        public Beginner() {

                  int radius = 200;
                  Point center = new Point (250, 250);
                  double angle = Math.toRadians(360 / n);
                  points.add(center);

                  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                      double theta = i * angle;
                      int dx = (int) (radius * Math.sin(theta));
                      int dy = (int) (radius * Math.cos(theta));
                      Point p = new Point (center.x + dx , center.y + dy);
                      points.add(p);

                  }
                draw (points); 
                  }

                   public void draw (List<Point> points) {
                       JPanel panels = new JPanel();
                       SpringLayout spring = new SpringLayout();

                       int count = 1;
                       for (Point point: points) {

                           quest = new JButton("Question " + count);
                           quest.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                            Font fonte = new Font("Script MT Bold", Font.PLAIN, 20);
                            quest.setFont(fonte);

                           add (quest);
                           count++;

                           spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, quest, point.x, SpringLayout.WEST, panels );

                           spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, quest, point.y, SpringLayout.NORTH, panels );

                           setLayout(spring);

                           panels.setOpaque(false);
                           panels.setVisible(true);
                           panels.setLocation(5,5);

                           add(panels); 


                          quest.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent p) {

                             JButton source = (JButton) p.getSource();
                             //where the problem lies
                             if (source.equals(points.get(0))) {

                                //some action....

                             }

                         }
                     });

                      }
                       }
          public static void main(String [] args){
                 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                 //set JFrame properties
                 JButton start = new JButton ("CLick here to start");

          start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent et) {
                  Beginner novice = new Beginner();
                  //set Beginner properties (remember it extends JPanel);
           }
              });

                 } }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I used one JButton with an arraylist of points to create 11 buttons, but they are only recognized as points, and I want to convert them into JButtons for easy use!

Comment: If you care for some code....let me provide?

Comment: what do you mean by point, and yes show me some of your code ?

Comment: I just asked a question! Why the downvote?

Comment: someone did that before seeing the edited version, again your point class is still ambiguous, where do you get that full package name, and please write the whole code at least a runnable snipped that i can replicate on my machine.

Comment: also the add and setLayout methods where are the definitions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probbaly you will need to add the missing lines into your code just like this, I've just tested it and it works.

- Import the `Point` class from `awt` package.
- Use the `main` method to execute your code by creating a new instance of the class.
- Also you need to extend the `JFrame` class to be able to call the `setLayout` and `add` methods.

  ```
  package javaapplication6;

  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Font;
  import java.awt.Point;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Random;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;

  public class Beginner extends JFrame {

      Random rand = new Random();

      int n = 10;

      static List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

      public Beginner() {

          int radius = 200;
          Point center = new Point(250, 250);
          double angle = Math.toRadians(360 / n);
          points.add(center);

          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
              double theta = i * angle;
              int dx = (int) (radius * Math.sin(theta));
              int dy = (int) (radius * Math.cos(theta));
              Point p = new Point(center.x + dx, center.y + dy);
              points.add(p);

          }
          draw(points);
      }

      public void draw(List<Point> points) {
          JPanel panels = new JPanel();
          SpringLayout spring = new SpringLayout();

          int count = 1;
          for (Point point : points) {

              JButton quest = new JButton("Question " + count);

              quest.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
              Font fonte = new Font("Script MT Bold", Font.PLAIN, 20);
              quest.setFont(fonte);
              quest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent et) {
                      System.out.println(quest.getText());
                      //do something else
                  }

              });
              add(quest);

              spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, quest, point.x, SpringLayout.WEST, panels);

              spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, quest, point.y, SpringLayout.NORTH, panels);

              setLayout(spring);

              panels.setOpaque(false);
              panels.setVisible(true);
              panels.setLocation(5, 5);

              add(panels);

              count++;
          }
          setSize(700, 700);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setVisible(true);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          new Beginner();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Try setting an actionlistener on each of them and see what you have!

Comment: When you want to set an actionListener on the buttons created, you get something like if (point.equals(points.get(int))) { //some action}. Which I don't want. I'd love to replace the point with a JButton object created.

Comment: why, to run the application ? I think using setVisible(true); from the extend JFrame class will suffice.

Comment: I edited my question to that effect!@JalalSordo, that is what I am talking about!

Comment: Try my new code, you will get a separate action for each button.

Comment: They are all printing "Question 11" on the console, nothing else!

Comment: Execute all the code , be aware of where I create the jbutton.